# Send event to other page/BLoC best practices

Tags: flutter, architecture, flutter-bloc

I want to make a list of leaderboards and add leaderboards. I have one screen with the list a plus button which opens a Dialog asking for leaderboard title then a loading indicator on submit. On completion I want the Dialog to disappear and a SnackBar to be displayed on the leaderboard list screen.

Here is my folder architecture:

```
leaderboard_list
├── bloc
│   ├── leaderboard_list_bloc.dart
│   ├── leaderboard_list_event.dart
│   └── leaderboard_list_state.dart
└── view
    └── leaderboard_list_page.dart
leaderboard_new
├── bloc
│   ├── leaderboard_new_bloc.dart
│   ├── leaderboard_new_event.dart
│   └── leaderboard_new_state.dart
└── view
    └── leaderboard_new_dialog.dart
```

leaderboard_new_dialog.dart :

```dart
class LeaderboardNewDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const LeaderboardNewDialog({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => LeaderboardNewBloc(
          leaderboardsRepository: context.read<LeaderboardsRepository>()),
      child: LeaderboardNewView(),
    );
  }
}

class LeaderboardNewView extends StatelessWidget {
  LeaderboardNewView({super.key});

  final TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<LeaderboardNewBloc, LeaderboardNewState>(
      listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
        if (state.status == LeaderboardNewStatus.failure) {
          Navigator.pop(context, false);
        }
      },
      child: BlocBuilder<LeaderboardNewBloc, LeaderboardNewState>(
        buildWhen: (prev, cur) => prev.status != cur.status,
        builder: (BuildContext context, state) {
          if (state.status == LeaderboardNewStatus.loading) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          return Dialog(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    BlocListener<LeaderboardNewBloc, LeaderboardNewState>(
                      listener: (BuildContext context, state) =>
                          titleController.text = state.title,
                      listenWhen: (prev, cur) => prev.title != cur.title,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: titleController,
                        onSubmitted: (value) => context
                            .read<LeaderboardNewBloc>()
                            .add(LeaderboardNewTitleChanged(value)),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                              .leaderboardNewDialogTitleLabel,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 24),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => context
                          .read<LeaderboardNewBloc>()
                          .add(const LeaderboardNewSubmitted()),
                      child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                          .leaderboardNewDialogValidate),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

leaderboard_list_page.dart :

```dart
class LeaderboardListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LeaderboardListPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => LeaderboardListBloc(leaderboardsRepository: context.read<LeaderboardsRepository>())
        ..add(const LeaderboardListSubscriptionRequested()),
      child: const LeaderboardListView(),
    );
  }
}

class LeaderboardListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const LeaderboardListView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => const LeaderboardNewDialog()),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body:
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

I though about a few ideas to solve this problem:

- Add a third BLoC above to manage this event
- Move the LeaderboardNewBloc provider above LeaderboardList so it can listen to completed event (success or failure)
- Add a LeaderboardListBloc provider above the dialog and add a specific event to display completion of the dialog.

What solutions did I missed, what is the preferred way to go ? What is the though process to choose between them in that case and more complex cases ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use one bloc to manage the leaderboard events/states?

Comment: If the problem is just showing the snackbar on LeaderBoard list screen, then you can show the snackbar using ScaffoldMessenger. This should show the snackbar across screens and your snackbar should be visible.

Comment: I could use one bloc for this example but I'd like to keep them separated because it will be more complex later. I also intend to move from dialog to an entire page so I'd like to have one bloc per page.

Comment: Indeed the ScaffoldMessenger is shared across Scaffold on different pages I did not know, in this example this problem can be solved like this. But what if I still want the LeaderboardListPage to receive the event to change somthing specific ?